# reinstall ubuntu mate 21.10 without losing data

Tags: mate, 21.10, reinstall

how can I reinstall ubuntu mate 21.10 without losing my data and installed packages.
[image: Startup page of Ubiquity from thumb drive]

[image: Second screen after selecting "install"]

[image: Third screen after clicking on "continue"]

[image: Last screen before actually starting the install]

Comment: Do you have a separate home partition? And what is "my data"? Your home folder? Every config file you've ever edited? Can you elaborate a bit? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can I believe; it's a QA-test install I perform at least weekly with Lubuntu (it's a QA *testcase* for them).

It's called "*Install using existing partition*" in the Lubuntu testcases; but this type of install works with all *flavor* and I use it myself with Ubuntu-MATE on occasion too.  See https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743 and search for "*Install using existing partition*" for what I've written there; where you'll note I refer to non-standard packages (`clementine` or a music player) & some music as examples of packages QA-testers can look for.

You perform the following steps

- backup all data (*it's easy to make a mistake*)
- boot the media you want to install
- start `ubiquity` installer
- select existing partition(s) but **ensure** you do **NOT** have format ticked for any

This will cause

- installer will note your manually installed packages
- erase system directories
- install the new system
- if internet is available install the extra packages noted earlier (*you need internet available!*)
- ask to reboot (*and won’t touch any user files unless you formatted*)

This type of install is triggered by the lack of format.

It works with Ubuntu repository software; sorry in QA-testing only Ubuntu repository software is used, so I have little experience with it on 3rd party software. Personally I remove all 3rd party sources prior to using this install so it works cleanly if it's my own box; and add the 3rd party myself later.

It also allows you to change release; ie. I used this install because I was lazy & just upgraded 18.04 systems to 20.04 without using `do-release-upgrade` as it takes a fraction of the time & has the ~same result (*sure metadata shows I re-installed; but the effect to me is identical! if I ignore datestamps on files & contents of history etc*).

I only pass the QA-test installs WHERE packages installed prior (*and I'm talking about pre-installed non-default packages from Ubuntu repositories*) get re-installed.  It's worked on all releases of Ubuntu-MATE (*for other releases I've used it back to Ubuntu 11.04 if not further back*)

ps:  *for at least one of my 18.04 to 20.04 installs; I'd used encrypted-partition which was a default on the initial install (maybe 17.10) but is no longer offered by default. For that machine I had to add a package during the *live* session before I started the installer (`ubiquity`) to ensure the system knew how to handle the encrypted partition, but outside of that `apt install` it was the same.*

Comment: Looks good. Just tested this method. It saves home folder of previous user. To save/restore list of applications I would suggest to run my [*srslsud* script](https://github.com/N0rbert/srslsud) on backup stage as `./srslsud.py all_save` on external media and then restore applications using `./srslsud.py all_load` on the reinstalled system. This will give complete picture.

Comment: Thank you.  I think this is exactly what i'm looking for.  I've made 2 generations of backups using Clonezilla so now I'm ready try on the 3rd drive.

I'm an electrical design engineer and now someone who plays around with the system.  All I want is for it to reliably run my engineering applications.  The patches and the over-the-air upgrades have made the system unreliable so I want to re-install the OS without having to reconfigure everything.  Again, thanks.

Comment: I downloaded the install 21.10 mate ISO on the date of my comment above.  Ubiquity does not resemble what you wrote up.  it does not give me any of the options you list.  It lets me pick the drive to install to and whether to install beside my existing malfunctioning version and that's it.  What could be the difference?
Thanks, John

Comment: With `ubiquity` it's the *Something else* option; you select your existing partitions but ensure they are not selected for *format* and continue as normal.  The lack of format triggers this install & it works identically for releases from 11.10 through to 21.10 as I describe (`calamares` was setup to mimic this Ubuntu `ubiquity` behavior when like positions were chosen).   *I can re-test this with Ubuntu-MATE jammy in the next couple of days; this isn't a QA-testcase for them so I don't do it often using Ubu-MATE but I know it works there*

Comment: Sorry to be so persistent but I must be doing something wrong.  I edited my original question to add screens shots of everything that appeared in Ubiquity.

I tried it both ways, clicking on "install" and opening a command line and typing "ubiquity".  My mistake is probably obvious but I don't see it.
Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: You appear to have added two screens that are identical.. so if that "*Updates and other software*" dialog I'd be checking your media for issues (did you verify ISO & write of ISO to media?).  Assuming that dialog didn't appear twice (*and it can appear to be printed twice on some video cards - but the second time it'll have a BUSY-CLOCK indicator and not pointer!*) you'll get the INSTALLATION TYPE. It's here that you select "*Something else*" which is the screen after your presented dialogs.  A Ubuntu-MATE *jammy* daily I booted offers "Install  alongside .. Erase Disk and .. Something else"

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Ubuntu is really just a collection of installed packages. Even if you reinstall the operating system in top of your existing installation, many of those packages will be overwritten.

Most user-generated data and many packages will be unaffected, but not all of them. There is no guarantee that your personal data and configurations will not be overwritten.

Additionally, reinstalling the OS without formatting might not even solve whatever problem has caused you to reinstall. It could actually spawn new problems if newly installed packages conflict with older files and configs that are not removed.

If you feel you need to reinstall the OS to fix some problem you can't otherwise solve, then you may as well do a wipe and a clean installation. Reinstalling is usually the exhaustive action you take when all else fails, so it doesn't really make much sense to do it "dirty". In either case, **back up your data**.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to switch the flavor, which can be done via the command line, without reinstalling and data loss.

Nearly all flavors are available inside of Ubuntu's official repository, so you can just download and install them.

For example, to install Kubuntu, install the package `kubuntu-desktop`. For Ubuntu (the one with GNOME), install `ubuntu-desktop`. You can run `sudo apt install <package name>` in the terminal to install them. This can prevent any data loss, and keep any third-party repositories.

If you have some reasons that you have to re-install Ubuntu and not just switch flavor, refer to other answers.