# I accidentaly deleted sda1 of my ubuntu sda system

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Can I restore efi system partition sda1 and if so how?
I tried making my own partition in gparted but it was miskonfigured

Comment: You can fix this by a reinstall of Ubuntu if you follow the process described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395018/reinstall-ubuntu-mate-21-10-without-losing-data Read the answer by @guiverc. Note that your data is a risk with this kind of process if you make a mistake so make a backup of any data you cannot afford to lose.

Comment: I'd suggest providing details of what you created in SDA1 and what partition you were trying to create.  We've been provided with no meaningful details as to what SDA1 contained; thus currently can't really provide any meaningful advice (*in my view anyway*) given I have systems here where SDA1 is my primary partition, others were its a ESP, others where its ... etc.

Comment: The advice I offered above assumes what you mean by “ efi system partition sda1” is that it is the small FAT32 partition sometimes called an ESP partition as per this Wikipedia entry : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition If it’s not that type of partition don’t follow the process referenced in my first comment above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: If you create a new ESP - efi system partition, you also need to update the entry in fstab with the new UEFI. `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid` and `cat /etc/fstab` then you can use Boot-Repair's advanced mode for full reinstall of grub & kernel or chroot & manually reinstall grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/